# SequelizeConnectionError: connect ETIMEDOUT Google Cloud Run

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, gcloud, ip-address

I have to build a platform to retrieve data from a sql database on another host,for this project I use js nodes with sequels.Locally I can connect without problems using id from the database and allowing access to my static ip,using the following code instance.

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(
config.DB,
config.DBUSER,
config.DBPASSWORD,
{
    host:'DB IP ADRESS',
    dialect:mysql,

    pool:{
        max:config.pool.max,
        min:config.pool.min,
        acquire:config.pool.acquire,
        idle:config.pool.idle
    }
 }
)

sequelize.authenticate()
```

https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/dialect-specific-things/

The problem occurs when I upload the project on google cloud platform, in cloud run I get an ip address that I save on my host to have access but the problem is the following, that ip address is constantly changing.

```
ErrorSequelizeConnectionError: Host '107.178.333.70' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server
```

Of course I read and was interested in working with VM and buying a fixed ip from google.
But after reading some forums on the internet, I would have a question if it would be possible to connect to sql instead of ip to use dns records?

Or using a hostname?

I tried to follow the documentation from the sequel, Dialect-Specific Things, I have integrated tedious modules,I found this example for mssql:

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize('database', null, null, {
   dialect: 'mssql',
   dialectOptions: {
       authentication: {
        type: 'ntlm',
        options: {
           domain: 'yourDomain',
           userName: 'username',
           password: 'password'
        }
      },
     options: {
         instanceName: 'SQLEXPRESS'
     }
  }
 })
```

Why am I trying with hostname because in php I managed this connection type:

```
'hostname' => 'domain.com',
'username' => 'dbUserName',
'password' => 'dbPassword',
'database' => 'db',
```

What I want is to discover an alternative to the connection by ip address or by dns records or by hostname in case I can't opt for the last option to purchase a fixed ip address.

Comment: Hello Pruteanu, I think the answer is, by default, a Cloud Run service connects to external endpoints on the internet using a dynamic IP address pool. This default is not suitable if the Cloud Run service connects to an external endpoint that requires connections originating from a static IP address, such as a database or API using an IP address-based firewall. For those connections, you must configure your Cloud Run service to route requests through a static IP address.  Go through this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/static-outbound-ip) I think this will help.

Comment: Did the documentation answer your questions?

Comment: Yes for the most part, I understand now I can set a Static outbound IP from the container image url,but it took me a while to figure out how to do it,my experience with google cloud platform is 6 days )).                                                                                      
From what I saw the connection with hostname is only possible at SQL Server

Comment: Can you give me details of `retrieve data from a sql database on another host`? Like where your SQL is set up ( on-prem, local or in GCP) and also what is sequels? I need to have a little more information and also did you find this `from what I saw with hostname is only possible at SQL Server` in any documentation? Can you link here the doc link.

Comment: [link doc](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/dialect-specific-things/), my sql db is set up on-prem.

Comment: Basically I have the client database set on on-premises, and it is going to have an application that will be hosted on gcp, I manage to take data from db use ip address at gc is not a fixed one, I read in the Dialect-Specific Things section about the ability to access these db using hostnam

Comment: I have posted an answer, please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is :  Create a [VPC Network Peering](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc-peering) ( [allows internal IP address](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/ip-addresses) connectivity across two Virtual Private Cloud (VPC) networks regardless of whether they belong to the same project or the same organization ) between your VPC and your on-prem network where your MySQL Postgres is hosted and then use [Serverless VPC Access](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/serverless-vpc-access) to connect a Cloud Run service directly to your VPC network.

[Serverless VPC Access connectors](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/connecting-vpc)  make it possible for you to connect directly to your Virtual Private Cloud network from serverless environments such as Cloud Run, App Engine, or Cloud Functions. Configuring Serverless VPC Access allows your serverless environment to send requests to your VPC network using internal DNS and internal IP addresses (as defined by [RFC 1918](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1918) and [RFC 6598](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6598)).

Here is the [documentation](https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-reach-on-premise-resources-with-serverless-products-747ebd37dc8e) which explains how to set this up.

Comment: Yes I managed to set an ip address for clud run following the documentation,fallowing this path VPC networks -> Cloud Routers -> IP addresses -> Cloud NAT -> Serverless VPC access  -> Cloud Run

Comment: Great, that works as well. Thank you for letting me know. Have a great day!

Comment: thank you for your time starting from the discussion I had on the stack and finally I managed to solve the problem.

Comment: It was all you, but thank you for accepting the answer. It was great working with you.